# Ubuntu 18.04 on dual boot PC on starting shows black screen with messages

Tags: 18.04

Ubuntu 18.04 on dual boot PC shows following black screen with messages after installing STEAM ETS2 game debian file (4.3GB). At that time 25GB free space was available.Also recently added 2GB graphics card.

Comment: Have you had a successful POST (boot) with that graphics card before?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please do not show pictures of text include text in the body of the question.

Comment: Yes, did used Ubuntu after graphics card adding.(more than  5 times)

Comment: Solved the problem. Uninstalled STEAM after recovery boot. Deleted related folder from /locals/Share. Then done the Ubuntu update.